# iptables на сервере с 2 ip

Tags: linux, ip, iptables

У меня на сервере 2 ip адреса с настойками в `/etc/network/interfaces`

[image: interfaces]

После того, как я закрываю порты, перенаправляю трафик на другие IP и т.д., то на сервере интернет канал виснет и новые соединения не принимает.

Comment: Приведите примеры

Comment: значит вы своими правилами iptables закрываете возможность новых соединений. невозможно ответить на ваш вопрос не видя ваших правил iptables и описания чего вы ожидаете от их применения

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса